# Most efficient way to send large payload to a web front-end

Tags: javascript, json, compression, protocol-buffers, msgpack

I have a grid that loads about 100k rows of data, which comes out to about 20MB. To get that data, we are currently doing something like this:

```
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()
return HttpResponse(data.json())
```

And then we will use `JSON.parse` in the javascript to then load that data into the grid. From end-to-end, what would be the fastest way to get that data from our database into our grid (with the one caveat that we do not allow the sql request in the front-end javascript code)?

Possible solutions I've thought of are:

- send things as-is, with no compression
- gzip the json data (almost zero work required)
- compress to lz4 then decompress in javascript (would require compiling cpp to javascript)
- use another format, such as protobuf or message pack

I'm not concerned about the size of the message, I'm only concerned about the end-to-end timing of displaying that data to the front-end. Basically, how long it takes the end-user to get a response.

(Note that I'm not concerned about breaking the data up into chunks, this is a very specific use case where a user has asked for all data to be loaded into an html table)

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for doing a data sync with indexedDb in browser. Wouldn't need to send all 100k rows each page load

Comment: @charlietfl that's what we'd be doing. This is more to load the data at the start for a user, or if there's ever a "full refresh" of the data.

Comment: I would also consider using custom data format if that affects the payload size by huge amount, plain CSV ? or is there a common prefix that can be omitted from all the 100k rows in the data e.g. a column just contains urls like http://example.com/?id=1, http://example.com/?id=3 ....I would just have 1,2,3 in that column of the csv. So I guess a custom data format with gzip compression can be a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this, receives large protobuf serialized message over MQTT, now display it to user in an HTML table format.

I have written [MessageToTable](https://abd-01.github.io/Flask-Protobuf/utils.html#protoserver.utils.MessageToTable) that takes in protobuf message and spits out an HTML table out of it.

Example:

```py
from example_pb2 import ExampleMessage
response_message = ExampleMessage() 
# parse from string, etc..
utils.MessageToTable(response_message, show_empty=False, tablefmt='html')
```

You see this in action [here](https://abd-01.github.io/Flask-Protobuf/telemetry.html)

If you have nested tables, [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) will convert the `<` and `>` to literal strings, you can overcome this by using `tablefmt='unsafehtml'`